# JPanel animation

Tags: animation, jpanel

Hy there.
I am trying to make a JPanel which reacts to certain events and plays a little animation. For example if I click on a button, it should flash red.(I need this to indicate when a file was successfully saved(green flash), or a error occurred(red flash).

I found some tutorials on animations, but I'm having a hard time changing it to fit my needs. For example most of the tutorials instantiate a Timer at the beginning. But I only need the timer to be active for that short amount of time where the flash is played and than stop. Also I need different animation types.(red flash, green flash...)

This is what I have got so far, which is basically nothing:

```
package MainPackage;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class StatusBar extends JPanel implements ActionListener{


Timer t = new Timer(10, this);
boolean stop = false;
Color color;

public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    setBackground(color);
}

public void confirm(){
    color = new Color(46, 204, 113);
    t.start();
}

public void warning(){
    color = Color.red;
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the finished class:
New animations can be added easily. And they also do not interfere with each other. So multiple states can be triggered simultaneously.

The **StatusBar.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class StatusBar extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

int width;
int height;
boolean bLoad, bWarn, bConfirm, bError;
Timer timer;
Color bgColor;
int xPosLoad, alphaWarn, alphaConfirm, alphaError;
float cntWarn, cntConfirm, cntError;
int cntLoad;
final int barLength = 200;

public StatusBar(Color bg){     
    width = getWidth();
    height = getHeight();
    xPosLoad = -barLength; 
    alphaWarn = 0; 
    alphaConfirm = 0; 
    alphaError = 0;
    bgColor = bg;

    timer = new Timer(10, this);

    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            width = getWidth();
            height = getHeight();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Background
    g.setColor(bgColor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // loading
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(xPosLoad,0, new Color(0,0,0,0), xPosLoad+barLength, 0, new Color(200, 200, 255));
    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    g2d.fillRect(xPosLoad, 0, barLength, height);

    // Green
    g.setColor(new Color(20, 210, 60, alphaConfirm));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // Yellow
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 223, 0, alphaWarn));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // Red
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, alphaError));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // step increase for all active components
    boolean toggle = false;
    if (bConfirm){
        if(cntConfirm < 1){
            cntConfirm += 0.01f;
            alphaConfirm = lerp(cntConfirm, 255, true);
        }else{ 
            bConfirm = false;
            cntConfirm = 0;
            alphaConfirm = 0;
        }
        toggle = true;
    }
    if (bWarn){
        if(cntWarn < 1){
            cntWarn += 0.01f;
            alphaWarn = lerp(cntWarn, 255, true);
        }else{
            bWarn = false;
            cntWarn = 0;
            alphaWarn = 0;
        }
        toggle = true;
    }
    if (bError){
        if(cntError < 1){
            cntError += 0.01f;
            alphaError = lerp(cntError, 255, true);
        }else{
            bError = false;
            cntError = 0;
            alphaError = 0;
        }
        toggle = true;
    }
    if (bLoad){
        if(cntLoad < 100){
            cntLoad += 1;
            xPosLoad = (cntLoad * (width + barLength)) / 100 - barLength;
        }else{ 
            cntLoad = 0;
            xPosLoad = -barLength;
        }
        toggle = true;
    }

    repaint();
    if (!toggle){
        timer.stop(); 
    }
}

private void startTimer(){
    if (!timer.isRunning()) 
        timer.start();
}

public void setBG(Color bg){
    bgColor = bg;
    System.out.println("Color: " + bgColor);
    repaint();
}


// Green flash
public void confirm(){
    // set values
    bConfirm = true;        
    alphaConfirm = 255;
    cntConfirm = 0;

    startTimer();
}

//Yellow flash
public void warning(){
    // restart values
    bWarn = true;       
    alphaWarn = 255;
    cntWarn = 0;

    startTimer();
}

//Red Flash
public  void error(){
    // restart values
    bError = true;
    alphaError = 255;
    cntError = 0;

    startTimer();
}

//Blue load
public  void loadStart(){
    // restart values
    bLoad = true;
    xPosLoad = -barLength;
    cntLoad = 0;

    startTimer();
}

public  void loadEnd(){
    bLoad = false;
    xPosLoad = -barLength;
}

private int lerp(float progress, int max, boolean inverse){
    float x = progress;

    float x2 = (float) Math.pow(x, 4);
    float g = x + (1 - x);
    float y = (float) ((float) x2 / (float)(Math.pow(g, 4)));

    y = Math.min(y, 1);
    y = Math.max(y, 0);

    int res = (int) (y * max);

    if (inverse){
        res = max - res;
    }
    return res;
}
}
```

And the **Example.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Example("Stat Example");
}

public Example(String title){
    super(title);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    StatusBar stat = new StatusBar(Color.black);
    stat.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 10));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton bConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    JButton bWarn = new JButton("Warning");
    JButton bErr = new JButton("Error");
    JButton bLoadS = new JButton("Start Loading");
    JButton bLoadE = new JButton("End Loading");
    panel.add(bConfirm);
    panel.add(bWarn);
    panel.add(bErr);
    panel.add(bLoadS);
    panel.add(bLoadE);

    this.getContentPane().add(stat, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);

    // Listener

    bConfirm.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            stat.confirm();
        }
    });

    bWarn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            stat.warning();
        }
    });

    bErr.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            stat.error();
        }
    });

    bLoadS.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            stat.loadStart();
        }
    });

    bLoadE.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            stat.loadEnd();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class flashclass extends JFrame{
    Thread th;
    Color defaultColor, flashColor;
    int i;
    boolean success;
    JPanel p;

    public flashclass(){
    setSize(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    success = false;
    defaultColor = new Color(214,217,223);

    p = new JPanel();

    JButton rbtn = new JButton("Red flash");
    JButton gbtn = new JButton("Green flash");
    rbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    success = false;
    flash(success);
    }
    });
    gbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    success = true;
    flash(success);
    }
    });

    p.add(rbtn);
    p.add(gbtn);
    getContentPane().add(p);
    }

    public void flash(boolean success){
    i=0;

    if(!success){
    flashColor = Color.red;
    }
    else{
    flashColor = Color.green;
    }

    th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    while(i<10){
    p.setBackground(flashColor);
    i++;
    try {
    Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    p.setBackground(defaultColor);
    }
    }
    });
    th.start();

    }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    new flashclass();
    }
    }
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: i wrote this code keeping Haeri's problem statement in mind that haeri wanted green flash when file is saved successfully a red flash when it fails to save. So what this code is basically doing is that it changes the background color of jpanel for a moment based on the value of boolean variable success if success is true: then green flash else red flash. the buttons are just there to simulate the flashing, but the users just need to use the method flash(boolean success) to change the background color of jpanel by passing a boolean to flash(boolean success) 
..continued in next comment

Comment: flash(boolean success) method dependng if file is saved successfully or not ie if file is saved successfully then call flash(true) for green flash else call flash(false) for red flash
The Thread.sleep() decides how long in millis the background color of jpanel remains either red or green

Comment: @bonney thank you for the answer. I compiled the code and it works fine, but It is not exactly what I expected. I posted the example code to show what direction I wanted to go. I used paintComponent to be able to implement even more animations like for example a "loading bar" (fillrect moving in the x direction).